# How to get n power ( square of a number or cube etc.) of a number in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two values one for base that is X and one for power N, how can a get X to the power of N ans.

any code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are looking for this:
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-math/pow.html
so:

```
pow(X,N)
```

If you want to implement it, you can have a look at here:
https://coflutter.com/challenges/dart-how-to-implement-exponential-function-power/
This boils down to this loop:

```
int power(int x, int n) {
  int retval = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    retval *= x;
  }

  return retval;
}
```

This only works well for integer n-s.

Comment: I have tried it already but unable to implement it into code can you create for me. thnks.

Answer (score 14):

For all of these examples with `pow` you need the following import:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
```

### 8²

```dart
final answer = pow(8, 2); // 64
```

*Notes:*

- If you are only squaring, then it's probably easier to do this:

  ```
  final answer = 8 * 8;
  ```
- `answer` is inferred to be of type `num`, which could be an `int` or `double` at runtime. In this case the runtime type is `int`, but in the following two examples it is `double`.

### Fourth root of 256

```dart
final answer = pow(256, 1/4); // 4.0
```

### 0.2^(-3)

```dart
final answer = pow(0.2, -3); // 124.99999999999999
```

That's basically the same as five cubed.

Answer (score 1):

btw Its working fine for double also

```
    double power() {
      double x= double.parse(t1.text);
      int y= int.parse(t2.text);
      double power = 1;
      for (double i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        power *= x;

      } ;


  return power;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
int m, n;
  print("Enter 2 numbers: ");
  m = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  int power = 1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    power = power * m;
  }
  print(power);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Just as a reminder, when you are interested in the powers of two, you don't need the `math` library, and you can use bit manipulation and left shift:

```
1 << 0 // 1
1 << 1 // 2
1 << 2 // 4
// ...
1 << 5 // 32
// ...
1 << 10 // 1024
```